Having difficulty installing vagrant-hostmanager
Hi so I am trying to install vagrant-hostmanager plugin. I keep getting this error message and I don't know what else to do, I'm using git bash for the installation.
Here is the error message:
Installing the 'vagrant-hostmanager' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Vagrant failed to properly resolve required dependencies. These
errors can commonly be caused by misconfigured plugin installations
or transient network issues. The reported error is:

conflicting dependencies logger (= 1.6.0) and logger (= 1.6.1)
  Activated logger-1.6.1
  which does not match conflicting dependency (= 1.6.0)

  Conflicting dependency chains:
    logger (= 1.6.1), 1.6.1 activated

  versus:
    logger (= 1.6.0)

  Gems matching logger (= 1.6.0):
    logger-1.6.0


I had the same issue. This fixed it for me -
export VAGRANT_DISABLE_STRICT_DEPENDENCY_ENFORCEMENT=1
There is going to be a new version with the logger dependency issue fixed but this gets around it in the meantime.
